# Share ad preview not visible

Tags: linkedin-api

We are experiencing issues with the preview, where the results differ between cases - sometimes it is visible and sometimes not.

This link works:
[https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A//espressohouse-sweden.at[…]reachmee.com/jobs/3405-coffee-shop-manager-till-kristianstad](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A//espressohouse-sweden.at%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dreachmee.com/jobs/3405-coffee-shop-manager-till-kristianstad)

but this one does not:
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A//espressohouse-sweden.attract.reachmee.com/jobs/3327-barista-till-boras

As it is the same webserver with the same settings on our side, I am wondering what could be going wrong? The expected results would be that the preview always is visible.